# No parallel loop with OpenMP

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, backtracking

I'm starting to study OpenMP on C++, and recently, I had this problem where I cannot make a for loop execute in parallel. No matter what, only one thread executes the loop in the following code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i<backtrackVector.size(); i++)
{
    if(findPath(backtrackVector[i])==true)
    {
        printResult(backtrackVector[i]);
    }
}
```

I've tried inserting the clause num_threads(n), but it also didn't work :( Does anyone has any suggestion that could help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged [C]?

Comment: how did you compile you're file? did you include -fopenmp compile flag (gcc/g++)?

Comment: yes, I included the flag -fopenmo.

Comment: How did you verify that only a single thread is executing? How did you compile (compiler, flags)? Did you get any compiler warnings? A bit more information would be helpful.